# Query Optimization while updating XML String in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm working with XML string shown below.

I have to update the XML string as follows:

- If the XML string contains 1000 records or more, it kills the query
- If the XML string contains < 1000 records, let it continue.

How can I do this?

**example data**

```
<root xmlns:json="http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json">
  <row json:Array="true" RowNumber="1">
    <Column json:Array="true" Name="Number" Value="1" />
    <Column json:Array="true" Name="HourFrom" Value="13.2" />
    <Column json:Array="true" Name="HourTo" Value="13.3" />
    <Column json:Array="true" Name="Rate" Value="0.895" />
  </row>
  <row json:Array="true" RowNumber="2">
    <Column json:Array="true" Name="Number" Value="1" />
    <Column json:Array="true" Name="HourFrom" Value="13.3" />
    <Column json:Array="true" Name="HourTo" Value="13.4" />
    <Column json:Array="true" Name="Rate" Value="0.907" />
  </row>
</root>
```

**Temp table creation**

```
    CREATE TABLE #xmltable(
                           Id INT Identity (1,1)  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
                           DataValue XML
                          );


    CREATE PRIMARY XML INDEX indexratesheet ON #xmltable
                    (
                      DataValue 
                     )
```

**Inserting data into table**

```
    INSERT INTO (DataValue ) VALUES(TheXMLfromAbove)
```

**updating the XML string in the table**

```
    DECLARE @i INT 1
    WHILE(@i<=1000)
    BEGIN
         UPDATE #xmltable SET DataValue.modify('insert <Column Name="ValidationComments" Value="{sql:variable("@validationcomments")}"></Column>
                              into (/root/row[@i=sql:variable("@i")])[1]')
   SET @i=@i+1
   END
```

Comment: This data looks very much like *better-to-store-in-a-table*, doesn't it? Is there a good reason to keep this in XML? I would store this in a normal table and create the XML when I need it...

Comment: Is this question solved? Do you need further help? Please allow me one hint: If this question is solved, it would be very kind of you, to tick the acceptance check below the (best) answer's vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Since  you've crossed the 15 points border yourself, you are - additionally - asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 2):

If you have to keep this with XML it should be much faster to shred the whole XML into a derivedTable and re-build it from scratch.

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE #xmltable(
                           Id INT Identity (1,1)  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
                           DataValue XML
                          );


    CREATE PRIMARY XML INDEX indexratesheet ON #xmltable
                    (
                      DataValue 
                     );
```

--Your test XML

```
    INSERT INTO #xmltable (DataValue ) VALUES(N'<root xmlns:json="http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json">
  <row json:Array="true" RowNumber="1">
    <Column json:Array="true" Name="Number" Value="1" />
    <Column json:Array="true" Name="HourFrom" Value="13.2" />
    <Column json:Array="true" Name="HourTo" Value="13.3" />
    <Column json:Array="true" Name="Rate" Value="0.895" />
  </row>
  <row json:Array="true" RowNumber="2">
    <Column json:Array="true" Name="Number" Value="1" />
    <Column json:Array="true" Name="HourFrom" Value="13.3" />
    <Column json:Array="true" Name="HourTo" Value="13.4" />
    <Column json:Array="true" Name="Rate" Value="0.907" />
  </row>
</root>');
```

--The query to shred it

```
SELECT r.value(N'@RowNumber','int') AS RowNumber
      ,r.value(N'(Column[@Name="Number"]/@Value)[1]','int') AS Number
      ,r.value(N'(Column[@Name="HourFrom"]/@Value)[1]','decimal(10,4)') AS HourFrom
      ,r.value(N'(Column[@Name="HourTo"]/@Value)[1]','decimal(10,4)') AS HourTo
      ,r.value(N'(Column[@Name="Rate"]/@Value)[1]','decimal(10,4)') AS Rate
INTO #derivedTable
FROM #xmltable AS t
CROSS APPLY t.DataValue.nodes(N'/root/row') AS A(r);
```

--The query to re-build it

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json' AS json)
SELECT 'true' AS [@json:Array]
      ,t.RowNumber AS [@RowNumber]
      ,'true' AS [Column/@json:Array]
      ,'Number' AS [Column/@Name]
      ,t.Number AS [Column/@Value]
      ,''
      ,'true' AS [Column/@json:Array]
      ,'HourFrom' AS [Column/@Name]
      ,t.HourFrom AS [Column/@Value]
      ,''
      ,'true' AS [Column/@json:Array]
      ,'HourTo' AS [Column/@Name]
      ,t.HourTo AS [Column/@Value]
      ,''
      ,'true' AS [Column/@json:Array]
      ,'Rate' AS [Column/@Name]
      ,t.Rate AS [Column/@Value]

      ,''
      ,'ValidationComments' AS [Column/@Name]
      ,'SomeValue' AS [Column/@Value]
FROM #derivedTable AS t
FOR XML PATH('row'),ROOT('root');
```

--Clean up (carefull with real data!)

```
GO

DROP TABLE #derivedTable;
DROP TABLE #xmltable
```

This is the result

```
<root xmlns:json="http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json">
  <row json:Array="true" RowNumber="1">
    <Column json:Array="true" Name="Number" Value="1" />
    <Column json:Array="true" Name="HourFrom" Value="13.2000" />
    <Column json:Array="true" Name="HourTo" Value="13.3000" />
    <Column json:Array="true" Name="Rate" Value="0.8950" />
    <Column Name="ValidationComments" Value="SomeValue" />
  </row>
  <row json:Array="true" RowNumber="2">
    <Column json:Array="true" Name="Number" Value="1" />
    <Column json:Array="true" Name="HourFrom" Value="13.3000" />
    <Column json:Array="true" Name="HourTo" Value="13.4000" />
    <Column json:Array="true" Name="Rate" Value="0.9070" />
    <Column Name="ValidationComments" Value="SomeValue" />
  </row>
</root>
```

### UPDATE

Try this query, it will work for all different column lists, but it will repeat the namespace declaration. This is not wrong, but very annoying. At the moment I do not have the time to think about a hack. Let me know, if this works for you.

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json' AS json)
,CTE AS
(
    SELECT r.value(N'@RowNumber','int') AS RowNumber
          ,r.query('./*') AS TheContent
    FROM #xmltable AS t
    CROSS APPLY t.DataValue.nodes(N'/root/row') AS A(r)
)
SELECT CTE.TheContent AS [*]
      ,'ValidationComments' AS [Column/@Name]
      ,'SomeValue' AS [Column/@Value]
FROM CTE
FOR XML PATH('row'),ROOT('root')
```

Comment: In below xml string only root node and row node is static column nodes in row node are dynamic how can i achieve from this as you suggests  <row json:Array="true" RowNumber="2">
    <Column json:Array="true" Name="Number" Value="1" />
    <Column json:Array="true" Name="HourFrom" Value="13.3000" />
    <Column json:Array="true" Name="HourTo" Value="13.4000" />
    <Column json:Array="true" Name="Rate" Value="0.9070" />
    <Column Name="ValidationComments" Value="SomeValue" />
  </row>

Comment: @PhaniRao What do you want to tell me with this XML fragment?

Comment: please now check the comment once am waiting for your reply

Comment: @PhaniRao Do I understand this correctly: The content within `<root><row>` is dynamic (different columns)?

Comment: @PhaniRao One more question: Is the `json:Array="true"` really needed? It would be easier to pick it out, as it seems to be the same all over (due to namespace issues...)

Comment: **json:Array="true"** is needed for me on front side

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133424/discussion-between-phani-rao-and-shnugo).

Comment: @PhaniRao Is this question solved? Do you need further help?